# Unable to login using IdentityServer4 from JavaScript Client

Tags: .net, oauth-2.0, openid-connect, identityserver4, asp.net-core-2.0

I have and .NET MVC core project which runs perfectly and is able to login using IdentityServer4 setup by me. However when I try to use the same IdentityServer to login using Javascript Client, I run into the error below:

[image]

I am using **oidc-client.js** at JavaScript Client to achieve it. I have my allowCors setting in place to allow CORS.

```
            services.AddCors(options =>
        {
            // this defines a CORS policy called "default"
            options.AddPolicy("default", policy =>
            {
                     policy.AllowAnyOrigin()
                    .AllowAnyHeader()
                    .AllowAnyMethod()
                    .AllowCredentials();
            });
        });
```

Please help me if anyone ran through the same problem. I followed the tutorial from IdentityServer4 itself http://docs.identityserver.io/en/release/quickstarts/7_javascript_client.html. I have verified that everything is in place according to tutorial but facing issues with it.

Here is the error being displayed in the browser console.

[image]

Comment: Please share the client configuration and where it’s used in The JavaScript. This is usually due to not having matching return urls.

Answer (score 0):

Turned out that client entry for JS application was missing in IdentityServer.

Added the entry below to fix it.

```
                // JavaScript Client
            new Client
            {
                ClientId = "js",
                ClientName = "JavaScript Client",
                AllowedGrantTypes = GrantTypes.Implicit,
                AllowAccessTokensViaBrowser = true,

                RedirectUris =           { "http://localhost:55697/callback.html" },
                PostLogoutRedirectUris = { "http://localhost:55697/index.html" },
                AllowedCorsOrigins =     { "http://localhost:55697" },

                AllowedScopes =
                {
                    IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.OpenId,
                    IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.Profile,
                    "api1"
                }
            }
```